# Labelling confusion in expl3: (public, private) Vs (global, local)

Tags: expl3

The [expl3 manual](http://get-software.net/macros/latex2e/contrib/l3kernel/expl3.pdf) shows that LaTeX3 is based on conventions. Among them conventions to correctly label variables and functions. They could be **public**/**private** or **global**/**local**. If there is someone who could make the difference (through an example if possible) be more unclouded.

Comment: Global: should always be set, cleared, modified etc. globally so that the change is effective even outside the current group. Local: should always be set, cleared, modified etc. locally so that the change is effective only within the current group. Constant: should not be modified i.e. should be set to a particular value and then remain that way throughout. I'm not really sure what you have in mind by the public/private contrast, even though I searched the manual for this distinction. Are you talking about some things being 'internal'?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A variable can be local or global; let me use a token list variable for the examples: the two instructions

```
\tl_new:N \l_aloui_whatever_tl
\tl_new:N \g_aloui_whatever_tl
```

define a local variable and a global one. The former should be set with functions such as

```
\tl_set:Nn \l_aloui_whatever_tl {abc}
```

whereas the second one should be set with

```
\tl_gset:Nn \g_aloui_whatever_tl {abc}
```

You can mix global and local variables; for instance, both the following calls are good

```
\tl_set_eq:NN \l_aloui_whatever_tl \g_aloui_whatever_tl

\tl_gset_eq:NN \g_aloui_whatever_tl \l_aloui_whatever_tl
```

but the reverse order is bad. A variable should *always* be manipulated with global functions if it has been declared global, with local functions if it has been declared local.

There is another distinction, between “public” and “private” variables, but it's mainly of a concern for package writers.

If you declare

```
\tl_new:N \l__aloui_whatever_tl
```

then you're stating that no package developer (or end user) should exploit this variable for their own usage, because it can disappear or be used in different ways in future versions of the package.

Similarly, a function declared like

```
\cs_new_protected:Nn \aloui_function:nn { ... }
```

is stated to be “publicly available”, so part of the “outer” interface, and that developers (or end users) can exploit it. Conversely, functions with `__` at the beginning of their name are “private”: they are used in your package, but you make no guarantee whatsoever that they'll remain in future versions.

To make an example, the kernel function `\cs_if_exist:NTF` is currently built upon the “private” function `\__chk_if_exist_cs:N`. The “public” function `\cs_if_exist:NTF` can be used by anyone and will not change in syntax and behavior in future releases*; the internal, “private”, function is used in the implementation, but nobody should rely on it, because the *implementation* could change.

<sub>* Well, the kernel is not stable at a point that *all* listed public functions are sure to be the same in future releases, but for a large part of the current functions this should be the case.</sub>

Comment: Is 'private' different from 'internal'? Because that's how I would have explained 'internal' vs. 'public'.

Comment: @cfr I used the OP's terminology, which is also common in programming.

Comment: I wouldn't know about programming. I realised you used the OP's terms. I just wasn't sure if this was another distinction and 'internal' really meant something different than I thought. I was confused by the question. I was just asking for clarification.

Comment: @cfr I'd say that “internal” and “private” are the same.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an attempt to explain the difference between constant, global and local variables and functions.

- **Constant:** should not be modified i.e. should be set to a particular value and then remain that way throughout.
- **Global:** should always be set, cleared, modified etc. globally so that the change is effective even outside the current group.
- **Local:** should always be set, cleared, modified etc. locally so that the change is effective only within the current group.

The following example attempts to illustrate this.

To keep things simple, I've done 2 things.

1. I've used non-expl3 syntax for unrelated aspects of the formatting such as `minipage` and `\hfill` etc. so that the focus is clearly on the manipulation of different types of variables. The exception to this is `\group_begin:` and `\group_end:` which seemed innocuous enough not to distract (hopefully).
2. I've picked a single type of thing to play with: token lists. So we have constant token lists, local token lists, global token lists etc.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \g_aloui_global_tl
\tl_new:N \l_aloui_local_tl
\tl_new:N \c_aloui_constant_tl
\tl_gset:cn \c_aloui_constant_tl { Do~not~change~me! }
Constant:~\tl_use:c \c_aloui_constant_tl
\tl_set:Nn \l_aloui_local_tl { Initial~value~for~local~token~list~variable. }
\tl_gset:Nn \g_aloui_global_tl { Initial~value~for~global~token~list~variable. }
\par
Local:~\l_aloui_local_tl
\par
Global:~\g_aloui_global_tl
\par
\group_begin:
  Start~group.
  \tl_set:Nn \l_aloui_local_tl { Within~group~value~for~local~token~list~variable. }
  \tl_gset:Nn \g_aloui_global_tl { Global~change~of~value~for~global~token~list~variable. }
  \par
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}{.8\textwidth}
    Local:~\l_aloui_local_tl
    \par
    Global:~\g_aloui_global_tl
    \par
  \end{minipage}
  \par
  End~group.
  \par
\group_end:
\par
Local:~\l_aloui_local_tl
\par
Global:~\g_aloui_global_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

[image: constant - global - local]

Comment: Nice demonstration.

Comment: In the light of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/451686/35864 you may want to rework the code for the constant a bit. I don't really know about LaTeX3, but I think you want `\tl_const:Nn \c_aloui_constant_tl { Do~not~change~me! }` and `Constant:~\tl_use:N \c_aloui_constant_tl`