# expl3's [check-declarations] fails to recognize a declared constant

Tags: expl3

The answer to TeX.SX submission [Labelling confusion in expl3: (public, private) Vs (global, local)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/308255/) dated May 6, 2016 was accompanied by the code below.

Why does loading `expl3` with `[check-declarations]` produce

```
!LaTeX error:"kernel/non-declared-variable"
!!The variable \csname\endcsname has not been declared on line …
```

with reference to the line `\tl_gset:cn \c_aloui_constant_tl {Do~not~change~me!}`?

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage[check-declarations]{expl3}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \g_aloui_global_tl
\tl_new:N \l_aloui_local_tl
\tl_new:N \c_aloui_constant_tl
\tl_gset:cn \c_aloui_constant_tl { Do~not~change~me! }
Constant:~\tl_use:c \c_aloui_constant_tl
\tl_set:Nn \l_aloui_local_tl {     Initial~value~for~local~token~list~variable. }
\tl_gset:Nn \g_aloui_global_tl { Initial~value~for~global~token~list~variable. }
\par
Local:~\l_aloui_local_tl
\par
Global:~\g_aloui_global_tl
\par
\group_begin:
  Start~group.
  \tl_set:Nn \l_aloui_local_tl {     Within~group~value~for~local~token~list~variable. }
  \tl_gset:Nn \g_aloui_global_tl { Global~change~of~value~for~global~token~list~variable. }
  \par
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}{.8\textwidth}
    Local:~\l_aloui_local_tl
    \par
    Global:~\g_aloui_global_tl
    \par
  \end{minipage}
  \par
  End~group.
  \par
\group_end:
\par
Local:~\l_aloui_local_tl
\par
Global:~\g_aloui_global_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Comment: I assume constants should be declared with `\tl_const:Nn` and used with `\tl_use:N \c_aloui_constant_tl`. The `:c` in function names does not mean *constant* which makes me think both `\tl_gset:cn` and `\tl_use:c` aren't quite correct here.

Comment: I noticed you frequently use a `c` argument type when it isn't really necessary, which happens when the function or variable's name depends on some parameter. Not here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have

```
\tl_new:N \c_aloui_constant_tl
```

So `\c_aloui_constant_tl` is empty when you issue

```
\tl_gset:cn \c_aloui_constant_tl { Do~not~change~me! }
```

You have `\tl_gset:cn`, so `\c_aloui_constant_tl` is used in a `c`-type conversion to an `N`-type base. As `\c_aloui_constant_tl` is empty, TeX tries to use the empty control sequence, which is shows as `\csname\endcsname`.

---

Not directly linked, but you should create constant token lists in one go:

```
\tl_const:Nn \c_aloui_constant_tl { Do~not~change~me! }
```

Comment: Oh I did not know you could define an empty control sequence (`\csname\endcsname`) to be something...

Comment: @moewe `\expandafter\def\csname\endcsname{whatever you wish}` Not that useful, though, because you have to call it like `\csname\endcsname` or with a backslash at the end of a line under `\endlinechar=-1` regime.

Comment: @egreg And hope that no-one has done `\expandafter\def\csname csname\string\endcsname\endcsname{confusing}` to make life 'interesting' :)